# Is there a more efficient way to install web apps on IIS rather than manual installation?

Tags: php, iis

I have a PHP web app that i would like to be able to ship as easily as possible. Some of the things it does are as follows:

- Call `shell_exec()` to execute windows executables
- Call `move_uploaded_file()` to move a file to a network folder
- Create temporary files for processing at later stages

Now these all require special things to be checked during manual installs such as the App Pool's user permissions on accessing network folders, creating files ect. A process that can be long and arduous. Normally this is the process i go through:

1. Check to see if PHP is installed on client's server. If not, download and install it first
2. Download zip archive from my website
3. Check if the server has already got the app installed. If so, copy and paste code files and finish.
4. If fresh install, extract zip into a physical path that will map to the web application in IIS
5. Open IIS, create web application under new or existing website
6. Ensure there is a database connection for the PHP application to talk to
7. Configure my app's settings (these are defined in my app)
8. Ensure the App Pool user that my app will be running as has permissions to do the things i mentioned above
9. Finally, test the app

So given that there is a long list of steps needed to install my app. My question is, is there a more efficient way to go about this? given that there are so many things to do. Can we create an MSI installer application or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all these steps can be automated. I would use a PowerShell script to perform all those actions.

Writing a Windows program as a MSI is another option, the tool depends on the available skill-sets in your environment.

To do this is not done in a few hours, you may need to learn about how to do the various things and then there will be a lot of testings. Different Windows versions are configurations have to be supported.

I went through such a process and it took much longer than planned, so you have to think about who much such a script would be worth for you.

If you only do a handful of installations every year it may not be worth investing the time creating the script.

You may be able to use [PowerShell DSC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249912.aspx) but you still have to learn, write configuration and test things.

Comment: So just to clarify, there is no real industry standard when installing? Companies can still do manual uninstalls without looking "unprofessional"? from what i can gather, our clients have very different server setups and your exactly right, a lot of time would need to be invested in testing an MSI (time better spent actually developing our application instead)

Comment: @kapetanios - No, not a real standard. People are working on things. [Chef](https://www.chef.io), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com) and PowerShell DSC are examples but I'm not sure they cover all your needs.